# bootstrap selectpicker title not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Not sure why this isn't working. I must be missing something basic.

```
<div class="input-group">
   <select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker form-control" title="Please select a type of fruit…">
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Pear</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm wanting it to display "Please select a type of fruit…" until the user selects one. It is displaying "Apple".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create one more option element, maybe with empty value:

```html
<select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker form-control">
    <option value="">Please select a type of fruit</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="pear">Pear</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

`title` attribute just provides additional information on mouse hover.

Comment: Any way to make it so that the first element isn't visible in the dropdown?

Comment: No, there is no way. If you want more flexibility you can try some of the many custom comboboxes. Like select2.

Comment: @dfsq There is always a way

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set it to be a **multiple select dropdown**, but limit the number of **selected items to 1**.

```
<select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-max-options="1" title="Please select a type of fruit…">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="pear">Pear</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, SIMPLE AND EFFECTIVE !

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `notooltip`; not sure if this works for single-choice selections as well, but you could combine this with Nikhil's suggestion to limit `data-max-options` to 1:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker notooltip"
        id="mySelect" title="Please select a type of fruit"
        multiple data-max-options="1">
  {% for opt in form.fruit %}
    {{ opt }}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, you did no wrong! in case your title is not showing you can get rid of the title and add another **option** with **data-hidden="true"** and **disable** attribute.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azizul/unqnsowh/7/)

```
<select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker form-control">
   <option data-hidden="true" value="" disable>Please select a type of fruit…</option>
   <option value="apple">Apple</option>
   <option value="pear">Pear</option>
   <option value="banana">Banana</option>
   <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```